# Arrays em loops

Tags: array, c++, loop

Eu não consegui resolver a seguinte dúvida:

Preencha os espaços em branco para imprimir todos os elementos de um *array* `arr` contendo 3 elementos:

```
for(int x=0; x<___; x++){______<<______[x]<<endl;}
```

Comment: Olá @français. Não há problema você apresentar um problema que talvez seja de estudos, mas apresentar um enunciado sem um aparente esforço de pesquisa esperando uma solução não é o foco desse site. Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Eu não consegui resolver toda a questão. Se coloca 3 no primeiro traço , no segundo se coloca a palavra cout, mas o que se coloca no terceiro traço?

Comment: O nome do array, @français. `arr`, no caso

Comment: @jbueno, muito obrigado, abraços.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo comentário sabe preencher os dois primeiros. Se deseja imprimir o *array* `arr`, deve imprimir o que? A variável que contém o *array*, certo? Mais especificamente deveria imprimir um elemento do *array* através do seu índice. Esse índice já está no código (`[x]`). Então só falta o nome da variável.

Se alguém te perguntar qual é a cor do cavalo branco do Napoleão, você sabe responder? Então a resposta já está na pergunta. Será que preciso escrever?